# My textbox value is automatically encrypting while inserting into the database. How to avoid this

Tags: c#, .net

When i am inserting textbox value into the database, the value is automatically converting to some alphanumeric characters For eg: textbox is for taking name in english language and on submit click event, textbox.text is getting value like "59061a90cce6b"

This is my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbx_StayName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

protected void btn_staySubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string result = "";
        result = fdal.InsertstayupdatedEnquiry(txtbx_StayName.Text, txtbx_stayEmail.Text);

        if (result == "1")
        {
           success message showing here
        }
        else
        {
            clearStay();
            h2_error.InnerText = "Error Occured! Please try again later";

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        objexc.ExceptionLog(ex.StackTrace.ToString(), "stayenquiry_Insert");
    }
}

#region InsertstayupdatedEnquiry
public string InsertstayupdatedEnquiry(string Name, string EmailId)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(CString);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertstayEnquiry", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", Name));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", EmailId));
                  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LogIp", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString()));
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
        result = "1";
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        objexc.ExceptionLog(ex.StackTrace.ToString(), "Festive.cs");
        result = "0";
        return result;
    }
}

#endregion


ALTER proc [dbo].[spInsertstayEnquiry]
(
    @Name varchar(50),
    @email nvarchar(50),
    @logIp nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin
    insert into tbl_stayEnquiry
    (
        Name ,
        EmailId ,
        logIp,
        LogDate
    )
    values
    (
        @Name ,
        @email ,
        @logIp,
        getdate()
    )
end
```

Comment: Please show us the code that do that. This is not a normal .NET textbox behavior.

Comment: protected void btn_staySubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string result = "", adminhtml = "";
                result = fdal.InsertstayupdatedEnquiry(txtbx_StayName.Text, txtbx_stayEmail.Text);

Comment: That doesn't look like encryption.  That looks like hexidecimal.  I don't think `txtbx_StayName` is a .pure Net textbox.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtbx_StayName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

This is my textbox

Comment: Then the 'encryption' is done in InsertstayupdatedEnquiry. What's going on in this function?

Comment: insert into tbl_stayEnquiry
(
Name ,
EmailId ,
logIp,
LogDate
)
values
(
@Name ,

Comment: when im doing from local or server,correct name is getting..

Comment: this hexadecimal values are getting from other users when submitting

Comment: Put your code please, we can't help you if you don't show us your code...

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", Name));` and inspect `Name`. Then look down the stack to find where its value comes from.

Comment: What type is the field in the table?

Comment: varchar(50) is the type

Comment: when im doing in local im getting the correct name

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself, not in comments.  Code in comments is unreadable, and we shouldn't have to hunt around to find your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Sneha,**

It may be browser issue. Please clear your cache or try in IE. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!!..the issue got solved now..i tried changing the datatype from nvarchar to varchar